# SQL statement that works for MS Access and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a web application that is using a Microsoft Access database as well as Microsoft SQL Server. Basically I am trying to eventually move the data from Access to SQL Server and want to write an inline SQL query that will retrieve the same bit value for both Access and SQL Server so when the conversion is made the incline code doesn't need to be changed.

MS Access allows you to set bit values = true whereas SQL Server requires you to have this same true value in single quotes when accessing its value (='true'). SQL Server allows you to use 0 and 1 as values to check against bits but Access doesn't.

Is it possible to write one SQL statement that returns the same values from both databases?

Comment: The best approach would be to stop writing your sql in your application. Move the sql to the database engine using parameters that have their values set in the application. That way it doesn't matter which DBMS you are using, the business logic is the same either way.

Comment: Different database provider = different way to access data, different data types, etc. I'd suggest to read DAL for both of them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971568.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Access and SQL server both set bit values false as 0 so you can write a select statement like this to return false

```
            SELECT * FROM Assets WHERE Active = 0
```

and another statement like this to return true values

```
            SELECT * FROM Assets WHERE NOT Active = 0
```

this will allow you to have one SQL statement that works for both databases as you convert your application from an Access database to a SQL Server database